# Why isn't my DbNull a singleton when I deserialise it using XmlSerialiser?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, singleton, dbnull

I've always assumed that DbNull.value was a singleton. And thus you could do things like this:

VB.NET:

```
If someObject Is DbNull.Value Then
    ...
End if
```

C#:

```
If (someObject == DbNull.Value)
{
    ...
}
```

But recently, I serialised a DbNull instance using the XmlSerialiser and suddenly it wasn't a singleton any more. Type comparison operations (like C#'s (obj is DBNull)) work OK though.

Code follows:

```
[Serializable, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(typeof(DBNull))]
public class SerialiseMe
{
    public SerialiseMe() { }

    public SerialiseMe(object value)
    {
        this.ICanBeDbNull = value;
    }
    public Object ICanBeDbNull { get; set; }
}

public void Foo()
{
    var serialiseDbNull = new SerialiseMe(DBNull.Value);
    var serialiser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(SerialiseMe));
    var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    serialiser.Serialize(ms, serialiseDbNull);
    ms.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var deSerialisedDbNull = (SerialiseMe)serialiser.Deserialize(ms);

    // Is false, WTF!
    var equalsDbNullDeserialised = deSerialisedDbNull.ICanBeDbNull == DBNull.Value;
    // Is false, WTF!
    var refEqualsDbNullDeserialised = object.ReferenceEquals(deSerialisedDbNull.ICanBeDbNull, DBNull.Value);
    // Is true.
    var convertIsDbNullDeserialised = Convert.IsDBNull(deSerialisedDbNull.ICanBeDbNull);
    // Is true.
    var isIsDbNullDeserialised = deSerialisedDbNull.ICanBeDbNull is DBNull;

}
```

Why is this the case? And how does it happen? And can it possibly happen with any other static fields?

PS: I am aware the VB code sample is doing a reference comparison and c# is calling Object.Equals. Both have the same behaviour with DBNull. I usually work with VB.

Comment: I've been messing with something fairly similar for a few hours now... I didn't even think to try IS DBNull.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although `DBNull.Value` is a `static readonly` and only exists as a single instance... when you de-serialize, the serialization code would be creating a new instance of the class `DBNull` from the 'data' in the stream. Since the `DBNull.Value` is simply a `DBNull` instance, there is no way for serialization to know that it is a 'special' instance.

**NOTE:**
For the same reason, if you make your own class with a 'singleton' instance that you serialize and then de-serialize you will get exactly the same behaviour. Although the deserialized instance will be indistinguishable from the original instance, they will not be *the same instance*.

Comment: Bah! A pox on magic serialisation code. Ta for the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Your c# code does not equal calling the .Equals method. With out having tested it Im actually pretty sure if you substituted

```
someObject == DbNull.Value
```

with

```
DbNull.Value.Equals(someObject)
```

it would give you the expected result. For some insides on the equality operator and the Equals method take a look at:
[Eric Lipperts blog post on that subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/09/double-your-dispatch-double-your-fun.aspx)

Comment: I didn't try that combination of Equals() before, but it doesn't work. Object.RefEquals(obj, DbNull.Value), Object.Equals(obj, DbNull.Value), obj == DBNull.Value, and DbNull.Value.Equals(obj) all return false after deserialisation.